# present continous or present perfect continous?

Tags: tense

Should I write 'I have been reading a book now' or 'I am reading a book now'?
I started to read one week ago and I haven't ended yet.
Thanks for help

Comment: if you started something in the past and have not completed the process/activity yet, Present Perfect Continuous is used. Simply say: **I have been reading a book.**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to say, of course.

In most cases the present perfect continuous has an *associated length of time of the action*.

> I ***have been reading*** a book now *for a week*.

The present continuous only conveys the fact that you're currently engaged in some activity.  If you don't care to relate *how long ago it started*, use present continuous.  For instance, you want to say that the book is about some topic you just touched in the conversation:

> I ***am reading*** a book now on this exact subject.

Comment: 'I have read about ten books in English so far, which were Agatha Christie’s criminals, and I have been reading the eleventh now. ' that is what I would like to write but I'm not sure if it's correct

Comment: Say, "I have read ten (why "about" if you know exactly?) books in English so far, all were Agatha Christie's detective stories, and I am reading the eleventh now".